# A simple case of universe inconsistency

Tags: coq

I can define the following inductive type:

```
Inductive T : Type -> Type :=
| c1 : forall (A : Type), A -> T A
| c2 : T unit.
```

But then the command `Check (c1 (T nat))` fails with the message: The term `T nat` has type `Type@{max(Set, Top.3+1)}` while it is expected to have type `Type@{Top.3}` (universe inconsistency).

How can I tweak the above inductive definition so that `c1 (T nat)` does not cause a universe inconsistency, and without setting universe polymorphism on?

The following works, but I would prefer a solution without adding equality:

```
Inductive T (A : Type) : Type :=
| c1 : A -> T A
| c2' : A = unit -> T A.

Definition c2 : T unit := c2' unit eq_refl.

Check (c1 (T nat)).
(*
c1 (T nat)
     : T nat -> T (T nat)
*)
```

Comment: "With Set Universe Polymorphism it works, so I guess there should also be a solution without universe polymorphism" <- what makes you think this is true?

Comment: @JasonGross I could not reply to your question, so I have updated my question with another reason why I think it should work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me first answer the question of why we get the universe inconsistency in the first place.

Universe inconsistencies are the errors that Coq reports to avoid proofs of `False` via Russell's paradox, which results from considering the set of all sets which do not contain themselves.

There's a variant which is more convenient to formalize in type theory called Hurken's Paradox; see [`Coq.Logic.Hurkens`](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Logic.Hurkens.html) for more details.  There is a specialization of Hurken's paradox which proves that no type can retract to a smaller type.  That is, given

```
U := Type@{u}
A : U
down : U -> A
up : A -> U
up_down : forall (X:U), up (down X) = X
```

we can prove `False`.

---

This is almost exactly the setup of your `Inductive` type.  Annotating your type with universes, you start with

```
Inductive T : Type@{i} -> Type@{j} :=
| c1 : forall (A : Type@{i}), A -> T A
| c2 : T unit.
```

Note that we can invert this inductive; we may write

```
Definition c1' (A : Type@{i}) (v : T A) : A
  := match v with
     | c1 A x => x
     | c2 => tt
     end.

Lemma c1'_c1 (A : Type@{i}) : forall v, c1' A (c1 A v) = v.
Proof. reflexivity. Qed.
```

Suppose, for a moment, that `c1 (T nat)` typechecked.  Since `T nat : Type@{j}`, this would require `j <= i`.  If it gave us that `j < i`, then we would be set.  We could write `c1 Type@{j}`.  And this is exactly the setup for the variant of Hurken's that I mentioned above!  We could define

```
u = j
U := Type@{j}
A := T Type@{j}
down : U -> A := c1 Type@{j}
up : A -> U := c1' Type@{j}
up_down := c1'_c1 Type@{j}
```

and hence prove `False`.

Coq needs to implement a rule for avoiding this paradox.  As described [here](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/7929#issuecomment-400376700), the rule is that for each (non-parameter) argument to a constructor of an inductive, if the type of the argument has a sort in universe `u`, then the universe of the inductive is constrained to be `>= u`.  In this case, this is stricter than Coq needs to be.  As mentioned by SkySkimmer [here](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/7929#issuecomment-400384621), Coq could recognize arguments which appear directly in locations which are indices of the inductive, and disregard those in the same way that it disregards parameters.

---

So, to finally answer your question, I believe the following are your only options:

1. You can `Set Universe Polymorphism` so that in `T (T nat)`, your two `T`s take different universe arguments.  (Equivalently, you can write `Polymorphic Inductive`.)
2. You can take advantage of how Coq treats parameters of inductive types specially, which mandates using equality in your case.  (The requirement of using equality is a general property of going from indexed inductive types to parameterized inductives types---from moving arguments from after the `:` to before it.)
3. You can pass Coq the flag `-type-in-type` to entirely disable universe checking.
4. You can [fix bug #7929](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/7929), which I reported as part of digging into this question, to make Coq handle arguments of constructors which appear in index-position in the inductive in the same way it handles parameters of inductive types.
5. (You can find another edge case of the system, and manage to trick Coq into ignoring the universes you want to slip past it, and probably find a proof of `False` in the process. (Possibly involving module subtyping, see, e.g., [this recent bug in modules with universes](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/7695).))

Comment: I'd love to fix bug #7929 but you have already closed it. Should I assume that it is already fixed? ;-)

Comment: Nope, my answer is not entirely correct; I've re-opened the bug, and will edit my answer here accordingly.

Comment: OK. I am waiting for your edit before validating your answer.

Comment: Edit has already been made (comment was at 3:00, edit was at 3:04)